# Converting an entire column of numbers in pandas to word equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with a dataset that has a column with the following set up:

```
'age'
 20
 25
 30
 35
 etc.
```

I am trying to convert to a column to the following:

```
'age'
'twenty'
'twenty-five'
 etc.
```

I tried to accomplish this using `num2words` imported library and doing a map:

```
df['age'] = df['age'].map(lambda x: num2words(x))
```

But I get an attribute error. The data originally in age is stored as an `int32` dtype, so I am not to sure what else would cause it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: works just fine for me

Comment: what is the error that u get

Comment: Nevermind you are right it does work. Not sure what was wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"k":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df.k.map(lambda x: num2words(x))

0      one
1      two
2    three
3     four
4     five
5      six
Name: k, dtype: object
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"k":["125","2","3","4",5.0,6.0]})
df.k.map(lambda x: num2words(x))


0    one hundred and twenty-five
1                            two
2                          three
3                           four
4                           five
5                            six
Name: k, dtype: object
```